# Apache misconfiguration - config works on apache 2.2 but not 2.4

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, rhel6, rhel7, cgi

I have a set of cgi scripts which run on a RHEL 6.x (with Apache 2.2) box fine.

There is a cgi-bin directory containing the scripts, plus an index.html (pure html) which serves as a front end to the scripts, allowing me to click on a button to invoke whichever script I want to.

Deploying the same set of scripts on a RHEL 7.x box with Apache 2.4, this config no longer works.

I found the "Require all granted" directive that I had to change between 2.2 and 2.4, but I think there must be something else too.

The error messages I get when trying to load index.html are as follows:

AH01215: (13)Permission denied: exec of '/path/to/index.html' failed
End of script output before headers: index.html

I have a ScriptAlias directive in place for my cgi-bin directory.

What I'm taking from all this is that apache is assuming that everything in this directory is a script, and it is trying to execute index.html via CGI.

Which I guess is fair, but this configuration worked in 2.2, so I'm wondering if there is some way to make an exemption for .html files, or will I have to rejig my directory structure?

edit:

SELinux was already disabled.

Scripts are delivered via an rpm file, which also includes a .conf file for /etc/httpd/conf.d/

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf is left at RHEL 7.x default for now

The .conf file as delivered by the rpm is this:

```
ScriptAlias /turnover-client/ /opt/tools/turnover-client/cgi-bin/
Alias       /turnover-client  /opt/tools/turnover-client/cgi-bin/index.html

<Location /turnover-client>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Which, at the moment, I have changed to this:

```
ScriptAlias /turnover-client/ /opt/tools/turnover-client/cgi-bin/
Alias       /turnover-client  /opt/tools/turnover-client/cgi-bin/index.html

<Location /turnover-client>
    Require all granted
    Options +ExecCGI
</Location>
```

Comment: Please provide your configuration. Also, check the selinux contexts of your script files and folders. selinux is enabled by default on RHEL 7.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I had already disabled SELinux.

Comment: Edited original post with more detail